# Parse.com login using email or username android

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

I have been trying to get this code to work, but I had no success.

All I want is to be able to login using either Email or username. I have already tried some methods but they did not work.

Here is the code I am using:

```
private EditText mUsernameEmailEtxt;
private EditText mPasswordEtxt;
private Button mSignupBtn;
private Button mSigninBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_authentication);

    // Get view references
    mPasswordEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    mUsernameEmailEtxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
    mSigninBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    mSignupBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_up);

    // Setup button click listeners
    mSigninBtn.setOnClickListener(new SignInOnClickListener());
    mSignupBtn.setOnClickListener(new SignUpOnClickListener());
}

// Input validation
private boolean isFormInputValid(String username, String password) {
    mUsernameEmailEtxt.setError(null);
    mPasswordEtxt.setError(null);

    // validate the username or email
    if (username == null || username.isEmpty()) {
        mUsernameEmailEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_username));
        mUsernameEmailEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    // validate the password
    if (password == null || password.isEmpty()) {
        mPasswordEtxt.setError(getString(R.string.error_password));
        mPasswordEtxt.requestFocus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

// OnClickListener Implementations
private class SignUpOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        String username = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        if (isFormInputValid(username, password)) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(AuthenticationActivity.this, RegistrationActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("ue", username);
            intent.putExtra("pw", password);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
        }
    }
};

private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        final String username = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        if (isFormInputValid(username, password)) {
            if (!username.matches("@")) {
                String email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString();
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo(email, username);
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseObject>() {
                    public void done(ParseObject object, ParseException e) {
                        ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();


                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
```

@maxib7
Ive tried your method. But i want a way to login with my Email or my Username. But this doesn't work either,

```
private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        final String username = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toUpperCase();
        final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString();
        if (isFormInputValid(username, password)) {
            if (!username.matches("@")) {
                String email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString();
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                if (user != null) {
                                    // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                            .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                    startActivity(intent);
                                    finish();
                                } else {
                                    ParseUser.logInInBackground(username, password, new LogInCallback() {
                                        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                            if (user != null) {
                                                // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class)
                                                        .addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                                                                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                startActivity(intent);
                                                finish();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
                                    ;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting ?

Comment: @AmitBhati it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I found out a way to achieve this some time ago, but forgot to post it here. Here's the final code,

```
private class SignInOnClickListener implements View.OnClickListener {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Get the username and password from the view
        final String username_email = mUsernameEmailEtxt.getText().toString().toLowerCase().trim();
        final String password = mPasswordEtxt.getText().toString().trim();
        if (isFormInputValid(username_email, password)) {
            if (username_email.indexOf('@') != -1) {
                ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                query.whereEqualTo("email", username_email);
                query.getFirstInBackground(new GetCallback<ParseUser>() {
                    public void done(ParseUser object, ParseException e) {
                        if (object == null) {
                            TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
                            error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            error.setText(getString(R.string.error_sign_in));
                            Log.d("error", "The getFirst request failed. Probably because no associated account found");
                        } else {
                            String actualUsername = (String) object.get("username");
                            ParseUser.logInInBackground(actualUsername, password, new LogInCallback() {
                                public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                                    if (user != null) {
                                        // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    } else {
                                        TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
                                        error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                        error.setText(getString(R.string.error_sign_in));

                                        Log.d("error", "email or password  invalid");
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });

            } else {
                Log.d("detector", "username_email detected as username:" + username_email);
                ParseUser.logInInBackground(username_email, password, new LogInCallback() {
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            // Hooray! The user is logged in.
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();
                        } else {
                            TextView error = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.info);
                            error.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            error.setText(getString(R.string.error_sign_in));

                            Log.d("error", "username or password invalid");
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it when I use parse to log in

```
/*
* Log user in
*/
public void setLoginButtonListener()
{
    Button LoginButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_login);

    // listen for click to login button
    LoginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            // views for login form
            final EditText emailView = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_email);
            final EditText passwordView = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.login_password);

            // Get the values of all the form fields
            final String email = emailView.getText().toString().trim();
            final String password = passwordView.getText().toString().trim();

            //Simple validation: if any field is empty then don't let the form submit
            if (email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty())
            {
                // show an alert dialog with error message
                Dialog.Builder newBuilder = new SimpleDialog.Builder(R.style.SimpleDialogLight);
                ((SimpleDialog.Builder) newBuilder).message("Please make sure you entered all the fields correctly.")
                        .title("Oops!")
                        .positiveAction("OK");

                DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(newBuilder);
                fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
            }

            // log user in
            ParseUser.logInInBackground(email, password, new LogInCallback()
            {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseUser parseUser, com.parse.ParseException e)
                {
                    if (parseUser != null)
                    {
                        // parse login was successful
                        // TODO do what you want here
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // Sign in failed. Look at the ParseException to see what happened
                        Dialog.Builder newBuilder = new SimpleDialog.Builder(R.style.SimpleDialogLight);
                        ((SimpleDialog.Builder) newBuilder).message(e.getMessage())
                                .title("Oops!")
                                .positiveAction("OK");

                        DialogFragment fragment = DialogFragment.newInstance(newBuilder);
                        fragment.show(getFragmentManager(), null);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: I want a method to login with either my username or my email @maxib7

Comment: it will still work. Just check if email.isEmpty() or username.isEmpty. If the username is empty sign in with email. If the email is empty, query your users for the person with that email. (emails are unique so there should be only one person with it) then take that queried email and sign in with it. So the user still thinks they signed in with username